# Xcode(7.3) is not launching Any Simulators on OSX 10.11.6

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator, xcode7.3

I was already having OSX 10.11.3 & Xcode with version 7.3 where I was able to work as usual. When I have upgraded the OS X to 10.11.6 . After upgrading to 10.11.6 Xcode is working fine but when I run the project in simulator, simulator icons pops up in dock and simulator state becomes 'Application Not Responding' in dock.

I tried to launch simulator directly without Xcode but still it behaves the same, it's icon pops up in dock and simulator state becomes 'Application Not Responding' in dock.

Anyone facing the same issue on OSX 10.11.6

Steps to Reproduce:
-> Update Xcode version 7.3
-> Update OS X version to 10.11.6
-> Launch Xcode with some workspace.
-> Run the app in simulator

Expected Results:
Simulator should be launched with app screens.

Actual Results:
Xcode shows that app is running but you wont find simulator launched.

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Pandit

Comment: Did you tried restarting your Mac and also force quit the simulator once. Helps me when the simulator hangs up with the application splash screen

Comment: yeah I tried. Issue persist even after restarting Mac.

Comment: @macpandit same issue i am facing too  , did you find any solution ?

Comment: restarting the mac  is worked for me